# Which line in a long Java 'try' block is throwing an exception?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, exception

Is there a way to find out which line in a try block is throwing an exception?

I'm working on Java in Eclipse which looks like

```
try {

  //Lots of code. Seriously. Lots.

} catch (Exception e){
  throw new OtherException();
}
```

I'm hitting an exception in the try block, (which is then caught). How do I figure out where it's being thrown from?

Problems

- The stack trace only shows the line in the catch block for the OtherException
- Removing the try/catch block isn't straightforward, as there are many exceptions declared as thrown which are required to be caught in order for the code to compile.

It feels like there should be a straightforward way of doing this.

Note: I didn't write this code ;-)

Comment: Answer: I set a breakpoint in the catch block and examined the Exception 'e'. Its call stack told me where it was thrown.

Comment: Debugging with breakpoints works wonders. :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the `cause` parameter for `Exceptions` ([see here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html#Exception(java.lang.Throwable))):

```
try {

  //Lots of code. Seriously. Lots.

} catch (Exception e){
  throw new OtherException(e); // Trick is here
}
```

This way you get the `cause` exception as well in the stacktrace.

Answer (score 4):

In Eclipse, you can set a breakpoint triggered by an exception. See [Add Java Exception Breakpoint](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/breakpoints/ref-addexception_viewaction.htm).

For this particular case, you'll need to ensure that "Suspend on caught exceptions" is ticked.

Once Eclipse breaks into the debugger, you'll have a lot of tools at your disposal. You'll see the call stack, will be able to examine variables etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `throw new OtherException(e);`. As the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html#Exception%28java.lang.Throwable%29) explains, this constructor *constructs a new exception with the specified cause*.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the exception e in your `OtherException` constructor when throwing it. It will give you the complete stack trace with the exact line throwing the exception:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    throw new OtherException(e);
}
```

If `OtherException` doesn't have a constructor that takes an `Exception` or `Throwable` you could do:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    OtherException o = new OtherException();
    o.initCause(e);
    throw o;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just print stacktrace or run on debug mode

```
e.printStackTrace()
```

Comment: Better to log it than print a stack trace.

Comment: I see, but sometime loggin is unnecessary if you want to debug the error only.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try printing out the error message to the console: `System.out.println(e.getMessage());`

Breakpoints are very useful though, since you can then trace through the code and see exactly when it gets to the catch block.

Comment: Better to log it than print a stack trace